# SQL - Group By Week to begin on a specific weekday without involving two transactions?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a query that returns the sum of rows for the last 10 weeks FRI-THURS.

It uses a group by to show the sum of each week:

```
WITH Vars (Friday) -- get current week Fridays Date
 AS (
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,(13 - (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())))%7,GETDATE()) AS DATE) As 'Friday' 
)
SELECT datepart(week, DateField) AS WeekNum, COUNT(*) AS Counts
FROM Table
WHERE DateField >= DATEADD(week,-9, (SELECT Friday from Vars)) 
GROUP BY datepart(week, DateField)
ORDER BY WeekNum DESC
```

The problem is every week starts on Monday so the Group By doesn't group the dates on how I want it. I want a week to be defined as FRI-THURS.

One workaround to this is to use DATEFIRST. e.g:

```
SET DATEFIRST = 5; --set beginning of each week to Friday

WITH Vars (Friday) -- get current week Fridays Date
   ... rest of query
```

However due to limitations on the interface I am writing this query I cannot have two separate statements run. It needs to be one query with no semicolons.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can elaborate if needed if there are any confusing parts

Comment: What do you want to show for WeekNum when the data spans year end?  Some Dec weeks would show as 50, 51, 52  whereas Jan weeks would show as 1, 2, 3 and would be sorted before Dec???  Does the OrderBy need to also have Year?

Comment: @donPablo preferably it just rolls to next year. (e.g. 52, 1, 2, 3) if possible

Comment: Could you post example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.  First pre-compute once the StartingFriday of 9 weeks ago, rather than doing that for each row.  Then compute the dfYear and dfWeek  giving them alias-es, where their DateField is after the starting friday.  Lastly, Count/GroupBy/OrderBy.

```
    Declare @StartingFriday as date =
             DATEADD(week,-9, (DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) +1) %  7) , GETDATE()))  ) ;

    SELECT  dfYear, dfWeek,  COUNT(*) AS Counts
    FROM 
        (Select  -- compute these here, and use alias in Select, GroupBy, OrderBy
             (Datepart(Year,(DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,DateField) +1) %  7) , DateField)) ) )as dfYear
            ,(Datepart(Week,(DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,DateField) +1) %  7) , DateField)) ) )as dfWeek
        From Table
        WHERE @StartingFriday <= DateField 
        ) as aa
    group by dfYear, dfWeek
    order by dfYear desc, dfWeek desc

-- we want the weeknum of the (Friday on or before the DateField)  
-- the % (percent sign) is the math MODULO operator.
-- used to get back to the nearest Friday, 
--     day= Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu 
-- weekday=  6   7   1   2   3   4   5
-- plus 1 =  7   8   2   3   4   5   6
-- Modulo7=  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
-- which are the days to subtract from DateField
-- to get to its Friday start of its week.
```

I did some testing with this

```
  declare @dt as date = '8/17/18';

  select ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) +1) %  7) as wd
         ,(DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,@dt) +1) %  7) , @dt)) as Fri
         ,(Datepart(Week,(DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,@dt) +1) %  7) , @dt)) ) )as wk
         ,DATEADD(week,-9, (DATEADD(day, - ((Datepart(WEEKDAY,@dt) +1) %  7) , @dt))  ) as StartingFriday
```